# Vue js how to Choice item in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

[image]

I have an array of alphabets, I want to make it so that the user can select one of these letters, then when you click on the button named "**All**" with an alert, the name of the selected letter is displayed, this construction looks like this

You can also look at this [project in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-breeze-2buk6)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="alphabet-container">
      <div
        class="alphabet-row"
        v-for="i in Math.ceil(alphabet.length / 6)"
        :key="i.id"
      >
        <span
          class="AlphabetLetters"
          :class="item"
          v-on:click="show(item)"
          v-for="(item, index) in alphabet.slice((i - 1) * 6, i * 6)"
          :key="index"
        >
          {{ item }} <br v-if="(index + 1) % 6 == 0" />
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="alphabet-btn">
        <button>All</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import _ from "lodash";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      alphabet: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 
      'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'],
    };
  },

  methods: {
    computed: {
      productChunks() {
        return _.chunk(Object.values(this.products), 4);
      },
    },
    show(item) {
      alert(item);
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
   .B {
     border: 1px solid #74c8c5;
     border-radius: 5px;
   }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a state like `selectedAlphabet` as @Melvynx suggested.
And you can move your click event from the alphabet to the button.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="alphabet-container">
      <div
        class="alphabet-row"
        v-for="i in Math.ceil(alphabet.length / 6)"
        :key="i.id"
      >
        <span
          class="AlphabetLetters"
          :class="{ 'blue-border': item === selectedAlphabet }"
          v-on:click="selectedAlphabet = item"
          v-for="(item, index) in alphabet.slice((i - 1) * 6, i * 6)"
          :key="index"
        >
          {{ item }} <br v-if="(index + 1) % 6 == 0" />
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="alphabet-btn">
        <button :click="show()">All</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import _ from "lodash";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      selectedAlphabet: 'A',
      alphabet: [
        "A",
        "B",
        "C",
        "D",
        "E",
        "F",
        "G",
        "H",
        "I",
        "J",
        "K",
        "L",
        "M",
        "N",
        "O",
        "P",
        "Q",
        "R",
        "S",
        "T",
        "U",
        "V",
        "W",
        "X",
        "Y",
        "Z",
      ],
    };
  },

  methods: {
    computed: {
      productChunks() {
        return _.chunk(Object.values(this.products), 4);
      },
    },
    show() {
      alert(this.selectedAlphabet);
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.alphabet-container {
  width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.alphabet-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.AlphabetLetters {
  font-family: "Second-Montserrat-Bold";
  cursor: pointer;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 14px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.Z {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
}

.blue-border {
  border: 1px solid #74c8c5;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.alphabet-btn {
  position: relative;
}

.alphabet-btn button {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #74C8C5;
  padding: 8px 40px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
</style>
```

Side note:

I think you can do away with the loop on the parent div (`alphabet-row`) and also remove the `slice` methods in the code, it should just work fine without it. If you're using it to control how many alphabets appear on a row, you can do that with only css.

Edit:

You've also put `computed` inside `methods` which is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a state like `selectedAlphabet` which contains the selected letter.
Your function `show` will set `selectedAlphabet` to the `item`.

In your HTML, you juste can add a conditionnal class that add a border if the `selectedAplhabet === item` :

```html
       <span
          class="AlphabetLetters"
          :class="item"
          v-bind:class="{ 'blue-border': item === selectedAlphabet }" <--
          v-on:click="show(item)"
          v-for="(item, index) in alphabet.slice((i - 1) * 6, i * 6)"
          :key="index"
        >
```